# Ping fail over official website

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I cannot reach spring official website. Everytime I am trying to load **spring.io** website it fails, this is an example:

```
$ ping spring.io
ping: unknown host spring.io
```

Any idea?

Comment: Works on my machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem by adding
additional DNS server 8.8.8.8
and additional search domain 8.8.4.4
sorry for the silly question.

[Jeryl Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8972567/jeryl-cook) thanks for kind reply.

Comment: great, thought it was networking :), Please 'Accept' my answer below if it helped. thanks